# Git push: set target for branch

Tags: git

I'd like to push my current branch (hp1) with

```
git push
```

and not

```
git push origin hp1:team/hp1
```

The remote branch already exists.

My local branches:

```
develop
master
* hp1
```

git remote show origin tells me:

```
Remote branches:
  develop  tracked
  master   tracked
  team/h2  tracked
  team/hp1 tracked
  team/n1  tracked
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
  develop  merges with remote develop
  master   merges with remote master
  hp1 merges with remote team/hp1
Local refs configured for 'git push':
  master   pushes to master   (up to date)
```

I already tried

```
git branch --set-upstream hp1 origin/team/hp1
```

and

```
git branch --set-upstream hp1 refs/remotes/origin/team/hp1
```

but both don't work.

My colleague has a local branch called as the remote branch (team/hp1) and the code above works for him. He gets at the end an additional

```
Local refs configured for 'git push':
  develop  pushes to develop  (up to date)
  master   pushes to master   (up to date)
  team/hp1 pushes to team/hp1 (up to date)
```

So maybe you can tell me what's wrong and how to fix it.

**EDIT**
my config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ***@***:***.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "hp1"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/team/hp1
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First of all, when pushing for the first time, do:

```
git push -u origin hp1:team/hp1
```

About -u option:

> -u
>   --set-upstream
>
> For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add
>   upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1) and
>   other commands. For more information, see branch..merge in
>   git-config(1).

Note from the manual that, this in itself will not determine what happens when you do `git push` the next time. When you do `git pull` while in this branch, it will fetch it from the upstream that you have set. But when you push, it will push to a matching branch ( in this case hp1 and not team/hp1)

For that to work, you have to set `push.default` config value to `upstream`. Once you set that, when you push from a branch ( just do `git push`), it will push to the upstream as mentioned by `branch.<name>.merge`

So do:

```
git config push.default upstream
```

About push.default:

> push.default
>
> Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is given on the
>   command line, no refspec is configured in the remote, and no refspec
>   is implied by any of the options given on the command line. Possible
>   values are:
>
> nothing - do not push anything.
>
> matching - push all matching branches. All branches having the same
>   name in both ends are considered to be matching. This is the default.
>
> upstream - push the current branch to its upstream branch.
>
> tracking - deprecated synonym for upstream.
>
> current - push the current branch to a branch of the same name.

Comment: thx, great explanation! Also, I understand now, why it is working for my colleague without setting the push.default

Comment: Another value for push.default is

simple - like upstream, but refuses to push if the upstream branch’s name is different from the local one.

Answer (score 4):

(March 2012): **Beware: that "upstream" policy could become the default one soon

(sometime after git1.7.10+)**:

See "[Please discuss: what "git push" should do when you do not say what to push?](http://git-blame.blogspot.fr/2012/03/please-discuss-what-git-push-should-do.html)"

> **In the current setting** (i.e. **`push.default=matching`**), **`git push` without argument will push all branches that exist locally and remotely with the same name**.
>   This is usually appropriate when a developer pushes to his own public repository, but may be confusing if not dangerous when using a shared repository.
>
> The proposal is to **change the default to '`upstream`'**, i.e. push only the current branch, and push it to the branch git pull would pull from.
>   Another candidate is '`current`'; this pushes only the current branch to the remote branch of the same name.
>
> What has been discussed so far can be seen in this thread:

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/192547/focus=192694

> Previous relevant discussions include:

- http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/123350/focus=123541
- http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/166743

> To join the discussion, send your messages to: git@vger.kernel.org

Comment: git 2.0 will change the default behavior for git push, but only to the "simple" mode which I don't think will do what you want. See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

Comment: @AlexanderBird Yes, you are right. I have documented that since: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10002469/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13751847/6309.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-u` option to `git push`:

```
$ git push -u origin hp1:team/hp1
```

Then, after that, you can do:

```
$ git push
```

Comment: for me, it just changes the configuration for `git pull`, the `git push` configuration is still the same (no push target set for branch hp1)

Comment: Can you post your config file?

Answer (score 1):

The following will allow one not to have to specify `-u ${branch_name}` for the first `git push`.

```
git config "branch.${branch_name}.remote" origin
git config "branch.${branch_name}.merge" "refs/heads/${branch_name}"
```

Granted, it's much more typing but not when it's in a script that sets up one's workspace. It also doesn't prematurely push the branch to the remote repo.