# git remote tracking branch pushes new branch

Tags: git, branch, git-push, remote-branch

I'm having trouble understanding what I did wrong when pushing to a remote branch.  Here is what I did:

I created a remote tracking branch locally named CP_Server_Release using the SourceTree GUI tool.  This branch is set up to track the remote branch origin/ICN_Portal_Server_Release.  I wanted a slightly shorter name for my local branch for convenience.

I made changes on CP_Server_Release and committed.

I then pushed my changes but I ended up creating a new branch called CP_Server_Release in the remote repo!  This is not what I was expecting which was to push my changes into the ICN_Portal_Server_Release.  So I figured something was wrong with the tracking set up.

I then deleted the new remote branch I created unintentionally and I ensured I was tracking the branch I want to by running the following:

```
moliveira-> git branch -u origin/ICN_Portal_Server_Release
Branch CP_Server_Release set up to track remote branch ICN_Portal_Server_Release from origin.
[~/src_git/icnportal_server/src/main/java]
moliveira-> git status
# On branch CP_Server_Release
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/ICN_Portal_Server_Release' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

That looks right to me.  I am ahead by one commit because last time I pushed a new branch instead of pushing my changes into origin/ICN_Portal_Server_Release.  It also looks like I am tracking the correct remote branch.

So now I want to go ahead and push my changes to origin/ICN_Portal_Server_Release.

```
[~/src_git/icnportal_server/src/main/java]
moliveira-> git push 
Counting objects: 109, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Writing objects: 100% (30/30), 5.05 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 30 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
To http://pdevicnos101.corp.intuit.net:81/git/cns/icnportal_server.git
 * [new branch]      CP_Server_Release -> CP_Server_Release
```

It created a new branch again!!  I don't understand why.  What am I doing wrong?  The only thing I can think of is it may have something to do with me not being in the root directory of the repo (/icnportal_server) but instead in a subdirectory (src/main/java).  If so, why is that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try next configuration (works for my 1.8.3.2 git version)

```
$ git config --global push.default upstream
$ git push
```

Comment: That works, thanks for the answer.  I dug around a bit on the values for push.default after I saw your response and found this useful post with more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170558/git-push-set-target-for-branch

Answer (score 0):

When you use `git branch` you're creating a new branch but not positioning on it. So after that you have to do `git checkout yourNewBranch`.

Instead of this, you can use `git checkout -b yourNewBranch` to create a new branch and position on it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I omitted that part but I believe I was on the correct branch or it would not have created a new one when I pushed.